# Is my reasoning of why this power mapping is onto the upper half-plane correct?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

Let $z_0$ be any complex number, $t$ any real number and $α∈(0,2π)$.

Find a conformal mapping from the sector $\{z:0≤arg(z−z_0)≤α\}$ onto the upper half plane, $\{w:Im(w)≥0\}$ such that $z_0$ is mapped to $t$.

**EDIT:**

My mapping is $$w = f(z) = (z-z_0)^{\large\frac{\pi}{\alpha}} + t$$

which easily shows that $z_0$ maps to $t$, as desired.  But I am not totally sure of whether my mapping is *onto* the UHP, as needed.  Here are my thoughts:

Suppose first that $z_1 = f(z) = (z-z_0)^{\large\frac{\pi}{\alpha}} + t$

for some arbitrary $z_1$ from the UHP.

Using Tanuj's suggestion (please see his answer below), and working backwards, then, looking at the arbitrary complex number $z_1$ from the UHP, and translating it by some fixed real number $t$, has the effect of translating the real part of $z_1$ -- so that $(z_1-t)$ lives in either quadrant I or quadrant II in the UHP.  So it must have argument *at most* equal to $\pi$.  And so $(z_1-t)^{\frac{\alpha}{\pi}}$ must have argument $\le \alpha$, and so we are done.  I.e., we have shown that any arbitrary $z_1$ from the UHP is an image point of the mapping $(z-z_0)^{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}} + t$.

What do you think?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a point $z_1$ in the upper half plane.

$$ z_1 = (z-z_0)^{\pi \over \alpha} + t $$

$$ \implies (z - z_0) = (z_1 -t)^{\alpha \over \pi} $$
So, all we need to check is if $\arg((z_1 -t)^{\alpha \over \pi}) \leq \alpha$.

Check that $\arg(z_1 -t) \leq \pi$ and we are done.

Comment: Hi @Tanuj, so, looking at the complex number $z_1$ from the UHP, and translating it by some fixed real number $t$, has the effect of translating the real part of $z_1$ -- so that $(z_1-t)$ lives in either quadrant I or quadrant II in the UHP.  So it must have argument *at most* equal to $\pi$.  And so $(z_1-t)^{\frac{\alpha}{\pi}}$ must have argument $\le \alpha$, and so we are done.  I.e., we have shown that any arbitrary $z_1$ from the UHP is an image point of the mapping $(z-z_0)^{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}} + t$.  What do you think?  Is my reasoning correct?  Thanks so much,

Comment: @User001 , Yes.

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks so much @Tanuj :-)